# Is it possible to fully switch the installed language of Windows Server after installation?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, language-pack, multilingual

If you have installed a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise in English language, can you later change that language to something else (like German)?

I know about the [Windows Server 2008 Language Packs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22681), but am wondering about their effectiveness.

I have installed language packs on Windows 7 in the past, but at certain spots, the original language still *shines through* (like during boot/shutdown operations). Something like that wouldn't be acceptable.

Optimally, the result would be equal to a system that was installed in the new language.

The reason I'm asking is, I'm installing a system for a German client. But during installation and setup, I'd like to use a system that uses vocabulary that I am familiar with.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to reinstall it?

Comment: @Ramhound Because it's so easy to reinstall a fully configured server? :)

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question to explain why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a blog post by Raymond Chen titled [How much gets localized in a localized version of Windows?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120716-00/?p=7123):

> Windows Vista mixed this up a bit by introducing Language Interface Packs, which are "mostly-localized" versions of Windows. Each Language Interface Pack starts with one of the "fully-localized" versions, and then re-translates a subset of the resources to suit the target language. Strings left untranslated receive the translation from the base language.

Which leads me to believe that, no, it is not possible to **fully** change the language of an installation, as the Language Packs only contain a *subset* of all material that is translated in a "normal", translated version.

Additionally, the [Windows Language Interface Pack FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20190127233116/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688177.aspx) mentions:

> The LIP packages do not have complete localization coverage. Only more frequently used UI is localized. Components not localized include administrative tools, system error messages, event logs, and others. Only the basic User Assistance (Help) files are localized.
>
> If an Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) computer with LIP pre-installed is purchased, and the LIP language is selected at setup, the setup experience will be localized as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.win2008workstation.com/win2008/installing-new-languages) installing Multilingual User Interface Language changes whole operating system language, which will solve your issue.